# How can i create JSON from TWO Database Table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

```
{
  "title": "Conversion",
  "list": [
    {
      "profile": "hp",
      "name": "coo",
      "desc": "lorem ipsum hp"
    },
    {
      "profile": "len",
      "name": "doo",
      "desc": "lorem ipsum len"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "title": "Online",
  "list": [
    {
      "profile": "kt",
      "name": "FOO",
      "desc": "lorem ipsum foo"
    },
    {
      "profile": "pd",
      "name": "boo",
      "desc": "lorem ipsum boo"
    },
    {
      "profile": "wh",
      "name": "soo",
      "desc": "lorem ipsum soo"
    }
  ]
}
```

i have two tables in my database

First Table : Categories ( id, CategoryName )

Second Table : Products ( id, CategoryID , ProductName , ProductDesc )

i want to get output like shared example with SQL sentense.

Accordin to my example;

Categories ( Conversion , Online)

Products ( Conversion(coo,doo) , Online(FOO,boo,soo) )

So guys, i want to get output with PHP and mySQL, please help me.

i have tried with that;

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM Categories c ,Products p WHERE p.CategoryID = c.id
$result1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
$json = [];

while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $json[] = [
        "Category" => $row1['CategoryName'],
        "Products" => array(
                "name" => $row1['ProductName'],
                "desc" => $row1['ProductDesc'],
        )   
    ];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: You could have a look at SQL Joins if you need to combine data from multiple tables.

Comment: i know how can use SQL Join but i don't know how can i get output like that

Comment: what output do you want to get? also, please giveout your MySQL 's table clearly, using MySQL ```select * from `category` ```&```select * from `products` ```